# How to make a button link within the iFrame load to a parent window?

Tags: iframe

Website Link: http://www.londonuw.com/category.aspx?id=MISC15

Under other products, click workers comp. You can see the page loads within the frame.

Here is the iframe code:

```
<iframe src="mywebsitelink" width="1000px" height="1550px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

What do I add to make this load in the parent window instead of the iFrame?

Answer (score 0):

In the i frame link add `<a href="" target=_parent>`.

The would open the page in parent and not in the iframe.

Comment: Im not sure where in the iFrame link to add this

Comment: Will it be before the "src" or before the ending </frame>

Comment: Glad that I could be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Found out what needed to be done. I inspected stackoverflow's post of iFrames.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp

When clicking on links in the center page, it will open a new window. But when i clicked on the dark bold menu items on the left it loaded in the parent window without needing to open a new page. Exactly what I needed!

Inspecting that element showed this code:
(a target="_top" href="default.asp" class="menu_default">HTML HOME

So all I did was replace "default.asp" with my website link and HTML HOME with my desired button name and magic!

**base target="_parent"  or   target="_parent" did not work for some reason

Thank you Vipul Behl for leading me in the right direction!